# cannot load settings .idea/workspace.xml

Tags: android, android-studio

I am receiving the following error in my android studio project.

> Cannot load settings from file
>   'C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects....idea\workspace.xml': Error on line 3167: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity

I have looked at the line and nothing seems out of the ordinary

```
    <state vertical-scroll-proportion="0.8210526">
      <caret line="85" column="14" selection-start-line="85" selection-start-column="14" selection-end-line="86" selection-end-column="8" />
      <folding>
        <element signature="imports" expanded="true" />
        <element signature="e#2694#3007#0" expanded="true" />
      </folding>
    </state>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In `project/.idea` you have broken `workspace.xml` file. you have to close Android Studio (Intellij IDEA), remove this file and start Android Studio. It will work..

Comment: thank you .. just for my understanding what is the file used for and does the system recreate it –

Comment: @the_big_blackbox I am guessing it is made by the Android Studio IDE

Comment: @the_big_blackbox it contains the layout of your workspace (e.g. arrangement of tool windows and such). Android Studio should recreate it, if it is missing, you'll simply need to rearrange things how you like them (things will go back to their default)

Answer (score 2):

This problem sometime may happen when a current user doesn't have enough permission to access `./idea/workspace.xml` file.

**SOLUTION:**

Go to your project root directory  and run this command `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER .idea/`

Comment: this finally solved it foe me after trying different things for weeks

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me also in my Flutter project, it was not enough to delete the .idea directory in the project root, I had to delete also .idea folder in android directory.

1- close the project

2- close Android Studio IDE

3- delete the .idea directory, but also android/.idea directory!

4- delete all .iml files

5- open Android Studio IDE and open existing project.

That's it, happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

This happened in both projects I had been working on in Webstorm 2020.3.3 after Big Sur update to macOS 11.2.3. It couldn't load any of the files from the projects' .idea directories.

I deleted the .idea directories and that fixed the problem... until I rebooted the next morning. Then it was the same issue. I checked permissions to make sure they matched my current user, but didn't help.

I then used ToolBox to uninstall and reinstall Webstorm 2020.3.3 and that fixed the issue.

I'll update this if it breaks again after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case the above solutions didn't work for anyone, I just removed all the projects listed in the "Recent Projects" list on the Welcome to Android Studio, Clicked on "Open" button, navigated to my project folder and opened it and everything was working back again. Not sure if this is a one-off case. I use a MacBook Pro and Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.2 Patch 1.